# Why I dont have the result of my current script with Django-wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I made my first step using Django with the help of the tutorial but I didn't understand the result of my action.

When I modify my python scripts and refresh my page, it's like there is a cache who store the old version of the scripts.

Example
I've got this error :

```
global name 'Poll' is not defined
Exception Location: /var/www/pythonRoot/scrapfull/polls/views.py in index, line 5

Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 111.  response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/pythonRoot/scrapfull/polls/views.py" in index 5. return HttpResponse("Hello, world. Vous etes a l'index des sondages.")
```

So, i see an error line 5 about my Poll model but there is no call of any Poll action in this tested script. 
But it's true that before, the line 5 was
    `latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` '

Why when I refresh, I don't have the interpretation of the current saved scripts?
Moreover, I can see some random result when I hit "refresh" frenetiquely. Why?

My conf : 
Apache + mod_wsgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, there *is* a cache for performance reasons. mod_wsgi keeps your scripts in memory instead of rereading them each time someone accesses your app.

If you are running mod_wsgi in daemon mode, the easiest way to tell mod_wsgi to reload sources is `touch`ing your `.wsgi` file:

```
$ touch path/to/your/app.wsgi
```

Otherwise you'll have to restart Apache.

(see also [this page](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode))

---

I recommend using Django's buit-in webserver for development as it automatically reloads your scripts.

Comment: I used Django's buit-in webserver and had the same problem. I had to kill and restart the webserver each time I modify my scripts. What is the best way to work on my scripts ?

Comment: @Makash No, this can't be true. Server started by `./manage.py runserver` is watching all your files and when you modify them it will reload them (it even prints on the console that it reloads them). Try again.